# H lookup in R - Merge data by Header Name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 Tables. I Want AHT from T1 to be merged in T2 in all rows.

**T1 contains AHT(Average Handling Time) of Target(s).**

```
Activities  Target1 Target2 Target3
Min.    1.8 2.6 1
```

**T2 contains Date wise Target(s).**

```
Dates   Target1 Target2 Target3 Target1_Min Target2_Min Target3_Min
01-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
02-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
03-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
04-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
05-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
06-05-2019  220 45  0   T1.Target1  T1.Target2  T1.Target3
```

Thanks in Advance.

Note: Both are data frame.

I have tried to used Match / Merge, but unable to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Not clear to me. What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Thanks for acknowledgment. I finally got the solution for my problem.

Comment: You might want to post it as an answer then.